# merging multiple maps efficiently while preserving order

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write an efficient function that merges multiple maps in the following way:

```
let map1 = { 'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'G': 7 };
let map2 = { 'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'G': 10 };
let map3 = { 'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'G': 1 };
output: map3 = {'A': 6, 'B': 9, 'G':18};
```

Below is my attempt. I am concerned that my function is not as efficient as it could be. Also, my function does not preserve the order of the elements. How can this be achieved? Thanks!

```
function merge(map1, map2) {
        if (map1 != null && map2 != null) {
            let objects = [map1, map2];
            const merged = objects.reduce((a, obj) => {
                Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
                    a[key] = (a[key] || 0) + val;
                });
                map2 = a;
                return a;
            }, {});
            return Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(merged).sort(
                    (a, b) => b[1] - a[1]
                )
            );
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) iterate over the list of maps. In each iteration, use [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of the current element, and iterate over it using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to update `acc` values:

```js
const 
  map1 = { 'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'G': 7 },
  map2 = { 'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'G': 10 },
  map3 = { 'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'G': 1 };

// group maps in one array
const merged = [map1, map2, map3]
// iterate over the array while updating an object
.reduce((acc, el) => {
  // iterate over current element's keys and update acc
  Object.keys(el).forEach(key => acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + el[key]);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(merged);
```